# How to solve problem with Java TreeMap when you use object as key?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, treemap, comparable

```java
package RecyclingJava.recycling;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class knot{

    //ArrayList<knot> connect= new ArrayList<>(); //ArrayList
    //Map<knot, Boolean> connect= new HashMap<knot, Boolean>(); //HashMap
    Map<knot, Boolean> connect= new TreeMap<>(); //TreeMap
    @Deprecated
    @Override
    
    
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Finalize object");
        super.finalize();
    }

    public void addconnection(knot knot)   {
        //this.connect.add(knot);  // ArrayList
        this.connect.put(knot,true); //HashMap
        //this.connect.put(1, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            //new Wezel() ;
            knot w1 = new knot();
            knot w2 = new knot();
            //System.out.println(w1);
            w1.addconnection(w2);
            w2.addconnection(w1);
        }
        
        //s.nextLine();
        //s.close();
        

    }
}
```

I have to use TreeMap to make connection between two objects, but i got this error when using TreeMap class RecyclingJava.recycling.knot cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable

I tried using compactor by it didn't work

Comment: "I tried using compactor by it didn't work" - *how* did you try doing that? It's not at all obvious how you want to compare two instances of `knot`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TreeMap` is sorted by the ordering of its keys. If you should not need a sorted map, you can replace `TreeMap` with an other class that implements `Map` (for example [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)). If you really need a sorted map you have to define the ordering of your key objects. You can do this in two ways:

A) Specify a `Comparator` as paramter for the constructor

```
Comparator<knot> comparator = ...
Map<knot, Boolean> connect = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

B) Implement `Comparable`

```
public class knot implements Comparable<knot> {

  ...

  public int compareTo​(knot other) {
   
    // TODO: return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this 
    // object is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object.
    ...
  }
}
```

When you do not specify a `Comparator` the `TreeMap` expects that you've chosen variant B and tries to cast your key object to `Comparable`. Since you neither specify a Comparator nor implement Comparable, the `TreeMap` complains with the described error.

For more details, please see the following JavaDocs:

[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html)
[Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)
[Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html)
[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)